# Form #states only work after change, but not on initial load

Tags: 8, forms

I've got a paragraph with a select field `field_colorschema`, depending on its value two other fields `field_image` `field_parallax`  on the same paragraph are shown or hidden. The code I've written works for most parts, but only AFTER change of `field_colorschema`. It does not set the correct state on page load.

```
function wt_base_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  /** @var \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig $field_definition */
  $fieldDefinition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  $parentEntityType = $fieldDefinition->getTargetEntityTypeId();
  $parentEntityBundle = $fieldDefinition->getTargetBundle();
  $parentEntityFieldType = $fieldDefinition->getType();
  $parentEntityFieldName = $fieldDefinition->getName();


  /**
   * Conditionally hide background image and parallax depending on row colorschema
   * http://agaric.com/blogs/conditional-fields-paragraphs-using-javascript-states-api-drupal-8
   */
  if ($parentEntityFieldName == 'field_pagebuilder') {

    /** @see \Drupal\paragraphs\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ParagraphsWidget::formElement() */
    $widgetState = \Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase::getWidgetState($element['#field_parents'], $parentEntityFieldName, $form_state);

    /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
    $paragraph = $widgetState['paragraphs'][$element['#delta']]['entity'];
    $paragraphBundle = $paragraph->bundle();

    // Determine which paragraph type is being embedded.
    if ($paragraphBundle == 'row') {
      $dependeeFieldName = 'field_colorschema';
      /* field_colorschema option value is one of ['--color-default', '--color-bglight', '--color-bgdark', '--image-bglight', '--image-bgdark'] */
      $selector = sprintf('select[name="%s[%d][subform][%s]"]', $parentEntityFieldName, $element['#delta'], $dependeeFieldName);

      // Dependent fields.
      $element['subform']['field_image']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bglight'],
          ],
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bgdark'],
          ],
        ],
        'required' => [
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bglight'],
          ],
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bgdark'],
          ],
        ],
      ];
      $element['subform']['field_parallax']['#states'] = [
        'visible' => [
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bglight'],
          ],
          [
            $selector => ['value' => '--image-bgdark'],
          ],
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried inverting everything negative logic (`invisible`...), because the default value on `field_colorschema` forces the other 2 fields to be hidden, but again it worked only after change, and not on the initial page load.

What am I missing so that `field_image` and `field_parallax` are correctly following `field_colorschema`s values on the intial page load?

PS: The paragraph subform is inside a [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) tab, but I think that doesn't matter, because the given code works after selecting values.

Comment: Can you add the options set in your field field_colorschema ?

Comment: Do you mean option values of field_colorschema? I've added them as code comment now, right below $dependeeFieldName = 'field_colorschema';

Comment: have you tried select[name*="
aka https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: The selector query is 100% correct, I already checked this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My given code works correctly. However, there is a bug in Paragraphs that instantly re-shows hidden fields from form API, see:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2868155#comment-12493576
https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2946856

Applying the [patch from issue #2946856](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-16/2946856-do-not-show-hidden-elements.patch) fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, good to see my patch worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ideas for working with this:

1. Frontend: Attach a small custom javascript library to the widget's render array (`#attached`) that will trigger a change event on the dependee element.
   This depends on the `$selector` being correct (and since everything works as expected after a change, it seems to be the case). The idea is to simulate a state change after page load, in order to get the states logic to apply.
2. Backend: Check the submitted value of the dependee field (`$form_state->getValue()`) and if there is no submitted values yet, check the default value of the form element (`$form['field_name']['widget']['#default_value']`).
   Once you know what the dependee's initial expected value is, you can conditionally set the dependent field to invisible by adding the `visually-hidden` css class to the widget (using `#attributes`).

Comment: Frontend is done inside Twig, it is for backend only. However, I can't use `[#attributes][class]` because form state API is toggling visibility with `style="display: none;"` and is not using classes. I've tried setting `[#attributes][style]` but that attribute is not rendered (maybe because of XSS filter?). I've checked the correct initial value using `$paragraph->get($dependeeFieldName)->value` --> seems OK. I don't know how to use  `$form_state->getValue('field_name')` for fields inside paragraphs though.

Comment: EDIT: `[#attributes][style]` gets rendered, it is just removed with JavaScript by form API after page load

Comment: Adding a class or more to a Form API element by using `#attributes` is the standard way to do this; you could work around the visibility toggling by working with the `invisible` state (reverting the condition) instead. Regarding the `$form_state->getValue('field_name')` part, you need to inspect what the returned value is structured like; I don't know why this would work differently for paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was a bug in Paragraphs itself, see my own answer

Comment: Ah, all right then. Glad you made it!